# Bring the objects produced by a R function to the main working environment

Tags: r, environment

I am trying to inspect the internal objects produced by a R function such as the example below:

```
myfunction <- function(arg1, arg2){
sum.both <- arg1+arg2
diff.both <- arg1-arg2
return(diff.both)
}
```

I am aware that I can bring it to the working environment by modifying the function itself:

```
myfunction.mod <- function(arg1, arg2){
sum.both <- arg1+arg2
sum.both <<- sum.both
diff.both <- arg1-arg2
return(diff.both)
}

myfunction.mod(1,2)
```

By doing that I can see the `sum.both` object by typing `ls()` in the console. However, I am looking for a way to get such internal objects from any existing function. Therefore, I tried `debug()` and `environment()` without success. Any ideas or directions on how to obtain internal objects from a function would be appreciated.

Comment: Objects created inside of a function disappear after the function finishes. That's one of the main reasons to use function. You don't want function variable names clobbering your own variables. Plus you need them clean each time you call the function. How exactly do you want to "get" these variables? If you need the function afterward, you should return it from the function. How exactly did `debug()` not work for you? It seems like you might not really want functions in this case. What is the problem you are really trying to solve. Is it just a debugging thing?

Comment: `debug()` needs interaction, which I am trying to avoid. Actually, such trick would be very handy  in debugging to me. That's the main reason I want it

Comment: There's nothing you can do without editing the function in some way. You can add `list2env(mget(ls()), globalenv())` before the function returns to copy everything from the local function environment to the global environment. Or you could add `on.exit({list2env(mget(ls()), globalenv())})` to the beginning of the function.

Comment: It might be interesting to look at [wrapr](https://winvector.github.io/wrapr/) or roll through their blog looking for 'captures' of state within function information (which might just be built atop functions suggested by @MrFlick), but they seem quite interested in these 'within' questions and code that can either extract or trigger.

Comment: An easy way to see multiple values in a function is to save them to a list and then return the list.  E.g. `mylist <- list(sum.both, diff.both) return(mylist)`.  Then view the list after the function processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess one easy way to modify an existing function is to use the `trace()` debugging tool. We can use that to insert code that will run at exit of a function to "leak" all the values from the function scope into the global scope. Here's such a function

```
make_leaky <- function(f) {
  fn <- substitute(f)
  invisible(trace(fn, print=FALSE, exit=quote(list2env(mget(ls()), globalenv()))))
}
```

Then we can test it with the following function

```
foo <- function(x, y) {
  a <- x+7
  b <- x*y
  b/a
}
```

We will use `ls()` to see all the variables at each step

```
ls()
# [1] "foo"        "make_leaky"
foo(5,2)
# [1] 0.8333333
ls()    # NO NEW VARIABLES CREATED HERE
# [1] "foo"        "make_leaky"   
make_leaky(foo) 
foo(5,2)
# [1] 0.8333333
ls()   # ALL VARIABLES FROM FOO ARE NOW IN GLOBAL ENV
# [1] "a"          "b"          "foo"        "make_leaky"
# [5] "x"          "y"
```